# IC for a 10nA Current Mirror

Tags: integrated-circuit, current-source

My laboratory developed an IC, where it will be necessary to have an external 10nA current source to supply it, with an accuracy of <5% and output resistance in the order of 5M ohms or higher. It was specified that the solution must supply a current mirror, which will enter on our circuit. We have a power source where we can make a 10nA reference from it, and use it in our current mirror.
I know how to implement a current mirror using transistors, but since precision is an extremely critical element in my system, I was looking for integrated circuits that have such characteristics.

I did not find an IC on the internet for this. In fact I even had difficulties to find current mirror ICs.
What I found was the "REF200", which features an integrated current mirror. However I was in doubt if it can be used for currents in the order of 10nA where precision is required. In the datasheet, this is not specified, as can be seen below:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ref200.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1610688356316

I would like to know what solutions for creating a precise 10nA CM with my specifications are viable? Is the REF200 feasible to generate 10nA currents?

Comment: it's a bit unusual to have a *minimum* output impedance (a maximum is much more common); specifying that does make sense considering the inherent thermal noise problem here, but I want to be sure there's no error in our understanding: Could you confirm 5 MΩ is the *minimum allowable impedance*, not a maximum.

Comment: 1) asking for an IC with a certain function is considered a "shopping question" and **off topic**. 2) as an IC designer (!!!) I am 100% sure that I can design a **much more accurate** current mirror circuit that sits on a PCB without using any current mirror IC but by using opamps, transistors, (precision) resistors and capacitors only. Also, on a PCB I can easily add trimming pots to fine tune the current copying (current mirrors actually copy currents but few people realize that) even further.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie might be that it was desirable to keep wafer complexity down, or that it's not your bread & butter Si wafer and doing this on-IC is hard...

Comment: It might work. You should try contacting TI to see if they can offer application assistance. The mirror may work down to 10nA. So the question becomes how do you create a 10nA reference current for the mirror? Maybe you would need two ref200's.

Comment: We need an extern current mirror because.we actually had no space on our chip to put it. There was a lot of projects inside our IC, and a limited number of possible encapsulations. The output impedance specified IS minimal.
My focus here is not about current mirror IC's. I just gave one that I found for reference of my problem (no specification for 10 nA), and if it could be used for it. What I most want to know is solutions for creating a precise 10nA CM with my specifications. Discrete components can be used, but I first thought (thermal) noise would be considerable high for it (?).

Comment: @mkeith I will try to contact TI to see it.
The reference can be generated by a current source that we have. We could not use it directly because of output impedance requirements.

Comment: Re: thermal noise: what's the bandwidth of what sinks that current? (orders of magnitude)

Comment: @Felipe Marcus just said what I also wanted to know. In my case, because a BJT current mirror involves PN junctions and therefore shot noise that you cannot escape. (Other kinds of current mirrors exist, obviously, with their own noise issues.) You will need to specify your worries about noise. Not just thermal, but all of it.

Comment: If it wasn't for the explicit request for a current mirror as opposed to a current source, 0.1V and a 10Mohm 1% series resistor would meet the spec. Is somebody overthinking it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller On a chip you only get the components that are available in the technology that you use. On a PCB you have a much wider choice of components. 10 nA is also extremely small, for good matching you need large on-chip components but at 10 nA the current density will be very low making design difficult as it is getting close to leakage currents, which are often poorly modelled.

Answer (score 3):

Just make a current mirror with a suitable op-amp, a couple resistors, and a low leakage transistor. 10nA +/-500pA is not very difficult at all under lab conditions.

You could (typically) use a BSS84 or 2N7000 (depending on the polarity of CM you need to make) at room temperature. For the op-amp use something with low Vos compared to the drop you can tolerate and (of course) low Ib.

Answer (score 1):

"It was specified that the solution must supply a current mirror" Why? All you need is a current source, right? How it's implemented shouldn't be a part of the spec.

The lab made its chip design job easier by making the precision current reference external - that's certainly reasonable. As the other answer suggests, doing this with an op-amp and a transistor is relatively easy.

Another solution would be to get a CMOS in-amp + op-amp on a single chip (IIRC those exist) and use a resistor to sense the current, and the op-amp's output as the current source.

Comment: good question, I was assuming this was for some CMRR testing in something like a difference current amplifier or so